# formvalidation.io bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, formvalidation.io

hello I was using formvalidation.io for bootstrap 3 and it was working , now I'm using bootstrap 4 and I want to just edit my old formvalidation javascript file to work with new bootstrap . this is the code I'm using

```
<div class="form-group text-danger">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="name" data-bv-field="name">
</div>
```

but the problem with this is that it changes only username color and not the input , I tried to edit formvalidtion js code to add like a class "border-danger" for the input , but I failed. any help will be appreciated.